# No IP address for Ubuntu VM constructed on VirtualBox and imported to libvirt/qemu/kvm

Tags: ubuntu, networking, kvm-virtualization, virtualbox, libvirt

I'm trying to install an Ubuntu 18.04 VM created on VirtualBox (not sure which host platform) and exported as a VMDK to libvirt/qemu/KVM under RHEL 7.8. It seems to import and start up OK, but I cannot access it because it has no IP address and 'virsh console' gets no response from the VM.

The virtio network interface is apparently created and assigned to the right network, but has no IP assigned to it, and shows zero activity.

What am I missing in the network setup? Do I need to modify the VM's kernel parameters?

```
[cfry@clippy vms]$ virsh domifaddr bionic-test-crf-2
 Name       MAC address          Protocol     Address
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

[cfry@clippy vms]$ virsh domiflist bionic-test-crf-2
Interface  Type       Source     Model       MAC
-------------------------------------------------------
vnet3      network    default    virtio      52:54:00:91:88:4f

[cfry@clippy vms]$ virsh domifstat bionic-test-crf-2 vnet3
vnet3 rx_bytes 0
vnet3 rx_packets 0
vnet3 rx_errs 0
vnet3 rx_drop 0
vnet3 tx_bytes 0
vnet3 tx_packets 0
vnet3 tx_errs 0
vnet3 tx_drop 0

[cfry@clippy vms]$ virsh domif-setlink bionic-test-crf-2 vnet3 up
Device updated successfully

[cfry@clippy vms]$ virsh domifstat bionic-test-crf-2 vnet3
vnet3 rx_bytes 0
vnet3 rx_packets 0
vnet3 rx_errs 0
vnet3 rx_drop 0
vnet3 tx_bytes 0
vnet3 tx_packets 0
vnet3 tx_errs 0
vnet3 tx_drop 0

[cfry@clippy vms]$ virsh domifaddr bionic-test-crf-2
 Name       MAC address          Protocol     Address
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

[cfry@clippy vms]$
```

Comment: Open the console and look at it.

Comment: I am unable to open the console. 'virsh console' may as well route to /dev/null.

Comment: That's a SERIAL console. Open the normal console with virt-manager or virt-viewer

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the answer to the wrong problem.

I had deliberately imported this VM using `virt-install` with option '--graphics none'. I had expected it to come up immediately without any further action. I was mistaken.

As occurred here: [How do I connect to my libvirt/qemu/guests ? (with no ip address)](https://serverfault.com/questions/718213/how-do-i-connect-to-my-libvirt-qemu-guests-with-no-ip-address), once I imported a new VM with '--graphics default', I found the problem was that the boot had failed due to a UUID mismatch, and the machine sat at an '(initramfs)' BusyBox command prompt.